# Rails 3 - Polymorphic and Global Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, polymorphic-associations

I have been trying to figure out how to properly use scopes for the following example.

Have a table Notes which has a Polymorphic Association to Items.  But I also allow there to be "Global" Notes, so  When I do a scope on Notes, I would like it to return the Polymorphic Association to Items and the NULL Polymorphic field, with some other conditions like IsReviewed type booleans.  I have tried to do the following but it isn't working well.

`scope :is_reviewed, lambda { { :include => [:category, :notable], :conditions => ["is_reviewed = ?", true] } }`

and then tried but doesn't return the "Global ones"

`scope :is_reviewed, lambda { { :include => [:category, :notable], :conditions => ["notable_type = 'Item' and is_reviewed = ?", true] } }`

and tried but doesn't seem to work correctly

`scope :is_reviewed, lambda { { :include => [:category, :notable], :conditions => ["(notable_type = 'Item' or notable_type = NULL) and is_reviewed = ?", true] } }`

Any thoughts or help would be highly appreciated.  THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually noticed that I had another problem that caused this scope to not work.  The following scope does actually work for retrieving the notable objects when one exists and you can search on the notable type in the partials or the helpers to do the correct logic for the type of notable.

`scope :is_reviewed, lambda { { :include => [:category, :notable], :conditions => ["is_reviewed = ?", true] } }`